# OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'rajendra'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask

I'm simply trying to connect my database using Flask with Python.

I'm getting this error from `1 week`, I searched and tried everything.
It says this on every time:

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'rajendra'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

Here is my source code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '1234'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'EmpData'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM User")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    print data
```

It show this [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld8ha.png).

And console error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/rajendra/PycharmProjects/untitled/myApp/run.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2015 19:00:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/rajendra/PycharmProjects/untitled/myApp/views.py", line 15, in nain
    conn = mysql.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 81, in connect
    return MySQLdb.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'rajendra'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2015 19:00:10] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2015 19:00:10] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2015 19:00:10] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2015 19:00:10] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2015 19:00:11] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2015 19:00:11] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=source.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use `MYSQL_HOST`, `MYSQL_USER`, `MYSQL_PASSWORD` and `MYSQL_DB` configuration directives: http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#configuration

```
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '1234'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'EmpData'
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
```

Comment: Somehow I missed that doc page. Thank you!