# Mysql error 1045 (Access denied for user) while using flask_mysqldb

Tags: mysql, flask

Operating System: MacOS

MySQL version: 8.0.16

Code to connect MySQL:

```py
app.config['MYSQL_HOST']='localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USERNAME']='root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']='123456'
app.config['MYSQL_DB']='Teaching_Sys'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS']='DictCursor'
```

The password is correct without any special characters inside and I already selected "use legacy password encryption" to initialize the database (Somebody solved the problem by using this trick)

and I already set up a table called Teaching_Sys

Code to insert new data into table by using flask:

```py
username=form_reg.username.data
email=form_reg.username.data
password = sha256_crypt.hash(form_reg.password.data)
#create cursor
cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",(username,email,password))
#commit to db
mysql.connection.commit()
cur.close()
```

and this is what the database looks like:
[image: Database schema]

The complete error message is:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'yiling'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

happended in line

```py
cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
```

While yiling is the name of my system account.

I also checked the user permissions of root@localhost

[image: Root user permissions]

Comment: So if you think you are logging in as 'root', but the system is denying 'yiling', that is your problem. 'yiling' and 'root' are not the same as far as mysql is concerned.

Comment: But I told the flask to login 'root', as the first part of the code. Why is there a 'yiling' in the error message?

Comment: Because you didn't deploy your updated code or the error is from a different file.

Answer (score 1):

[OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'rajendra'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187208/operationalerror-1045-access-denied-for-user-rajendralocalhost-using-p)

The answer is here

```
app.config['MYSQL_USERNAME']='root'
```

should be

```
app.config['MYSQL_USER']='root'
```